# Confused about how to implement value and a restriction parameter

Tags: c#, class, oop, constructor

Putting some finishing touches on a class assignment, but I'm running into problems with two concepts.

Here is the assignment: write a C# .NET Framework console application to demonstrate the use cases of properties in C#. The application will do the following to accomplish this goal.

1. Log every instance of writing of a private field within a property setter. Before the program exits, output the activity log to the screen. Set the value of each property of each student to facilitate testing and operation of this logging functionality.
2. Choose at least one property for students, and make sure its setter has logic in it other than the default auto property setter code. Logging is not counted for these requirements. See the WatchDogAbility example from Chapter 3 slides/text. Historically, systems have allowed students to restrict the viewing of their personal information. Implement this system here, by ensuring the getters of properties check for this value before returning student information. Student ID and Name are exempt from needing to be checked.
3. Submit a screenshot of you stopping your program in debug mode in Visual Studio. Set one of the Student object's properties. Pause on the line where the new value is written to the private field. Make sure the new value is shown on the screen in your image (see example below, using Alt + Print Screen). Output all data for all students, let’s say a minimum of 10 students, with at least one with restricted personal information.

I am lost as to how to "log every instance of writing of a private field within a property setter" and I am also confused as to how I can satisfy this requirement, "Historically, systems have allowed students to restrict the viewing of their personal information. Implement this system here, by ensuring the getters of properties check for this value before returning student information. Student ID and Name are exempt from needing to be checked."

Below is the code I have thus far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_3
{
    // Student Class
    public class Student
    {
        // Class Fields
        private int _graddate;
        public int _id, _total;
        public string _name, _major, _startdate, _state, _country, _email, _mailaddress;
        public long _phonenumber;

        // Name Propery Constructor - Read Only
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._id;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this._name;
            }
        }

        public int Total
        {
            get
            {
                return this._total;
            }
            set
            {
                this._total = value;
                Console.WriteLine($"Set Total to {value}");
            }
        }

        public int Graddate
        {
            get
            {
                return _graddate;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value < 2020)
                {
                    this._graddate = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._graddate = value;
                }
            }
        }

        // Constructor
        public Student(int id, string name, string major, string startdate, int graddate, string state, string country, string email, long phonenumber, string mailaddress)
        {
            this._id = id;
            this._name = name;
            this._major = major;
            this._startdate = startdate;
            this._graddate = graddate;
            this._state = state;
            this._country = country;
            this._email = email;
            this._phonenumber = phonenumber;
            this._mailaddress = mailaddress;
        }

        public Student(int total)
        {
            this._total = total;
        }
    }

    // Main class
    public class MainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student perone = new Student(07211964, "Ryu", "Physical Education", "July 21, 1964", 2021, "Shimane", "Japan", "Hadoken@gmail.com", 81369207750, "285 Suzaku Castle");
            Student pertwo = new Student(02141965, "Ken", "Hospitality", "February 14, 1965", 2021, "California", "United States", "Shoryuken@gmail.com", 6503506500, "101 Battle Harbor");
            Student perthree = new Student(11031960, "E.Honda", "Culinary Arts", "November 03, 1960", 2016, "Higashi Komagata", "Japan", "KillerHeadRam@gmail.com", 810669203600, "462 Kapukon Yu");
            Student perfour = new Student(12231960, "Guile", "Aviation", "December 23, 1960", 2018, "Texas", "United States", "SonicBoom@gmail.com", 3109435470, "119 Air Force Base");
            Student perfive = new Student(03011968, "Chun-Li", "Criminology", "March 01, 1968", 2020, "North Point", "Hong Kong", "Hyakuretsukyaku@gmail.com", 85223661001, "911 Taiping Road");
            Student persix = new Student(02121966, "Blanka", "Electrical Engineering", "February 12, 1966", 2030, "Brasilia", "Brazil", "ShoutOfEarth@gmail.com", 4908001801976, "777 Amazon River Basin");
            Student perseven = new Student(06011956, "Zangief", "Russian", "June 01, 1956", 2013, "Moscow", "Russia", "RedCyclone@gmail.com", 4408005876638, "360 Big Factory");
            Student pereight = new Student(11221952, "Dhalsim", "Mental Health Services", "November 22, 1952", 2008, "New Delhi", "India", "YogaFire@gmail.com", 330800909617, "695 Marharaja's Palace");
            Student pernine = new Student(01271967, "Vega", "Psychology", "January 27, 1967", 2026, "Madrid", "Spain", "IzunaDrop@gmail.com", 34900811390, "187 Flamenco Tavern");
            Student perten = new Student(07021955, "Sagat", "Physical Education", "July 02, 1955", 2050, "Ayutthaya", "Thailand", "VanillaSagat@gmail.com", 39800928830, "311 King's Court");

            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9} \n", perone.Id, perone.Name, perone._major, perone._startdate, perone.Graddate, perone._state, perone._country, perone._email, perone._phonenumber, perone._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", pertwo.Id, pertwo.Name, pertwo._major, pertwo._startdate, pertwo.Graddate, pertwo._state, pertwo._country, pertwo._email, pertwo._phonenumber, pertwo._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", perthree.Id, perthree.Name, perthree._major, perthree._startdate, perthree.Graddate, perthree._state, perthree._country, perthree._email, perthree._phonenumber, perthree._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", perfour.Id, perfour.Name, perfour._major, perfour._startdate, perfour.Graddate, perfour._state, perfour._country, perfour._email, perfour._phonenumber, perfour._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", perfive.Id, perfive.Name, perfive._major, perfive._startdate, perfive.Graddate, perfive._state, perfive._country, perfive._email, perfive._phonenumber, perfive._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", persix.Id, persix.Name, persix._major, persix._startdate, persix.Graddate, persix._state, persix._country, persix._email, persix._phonenumber, persix._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", perseven.Id, perseven.Name, perseven._major, perseven._startdate, perseven.Graddate, perseven._state, perseven._country, perseven._email, perseven._phonenumber, perseven._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", pereight.Id, pereight.Name, pereight._major, pereight._startdate, pereight.Graddate, pereight._state, pereight._country, pereight._email, pereight._phonenumber, pereight._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", pernine.Id, pernine.Name, pernine._major, pernine._startdate, pernine.Graddate, pernine._state, pernine._country, pernine._email, pernine._phonenumber, pernine._mailaddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: {0}, Student Name: {1}, Major: {2}, School Start Date: {3}, School Graduation Date: {4}, State/Territory: {5}, Country: {6}, E-Mail: {7}, Phone Number: {8}, Mail Address: {9}", perten.Id, perten.Name, perten._major, perten._startdate, perten.Graddate, perten._state, perten._country, perten._email, perten._phonenumber, perten._mailaddress);

            Console.WriteLine("Instances of writing of a private field within a setter: {0}", Student.Total);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and explanations!

Comment: You're `log[ging] every instance of writing of a private field within a property setter` in your `Total` property.  A common C# construct is to have a property backed by a private field.  In this case, `_total` is our private field.  We expose this field with the `Total` property.  Dig?

Comment: I dig man, thanks for explaining it for me. So I create a ```private int  _total;``` in my Student class, and I can make a constructor for it via 
```
        public Student(int total)
        {
            this._total = total;
        } 
```

How should I implement it within my main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help get you started:

```
public class Student
{
    private static List<string> _log = new List<string>();

    public string _major;
    public string _startdate;
    public string _state;
    public string _country;
    public string _mailaddress;
    public long _phonenumber;

    private int _id;
    public int Id { get { return _id; } }

    public string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }

    private int _graddate;
    public int Graddate
    {
        get { return _graddate; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 2020)
            {
                this._graddate = 0;
                _log.Add($"Set {_id}.Graddate to `0` (attempted `{value}`)");
            }
            else
            {
                this._graddate = value;
                _log.Add($"Set {_id}.Graddate to `{value}`");
            }
        }
    }

    public string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            this._email = value;
            _log.Add($"Set {_id}.Email to `{value}`");
        }
    }

    public static string GetLog()
    {
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, _log);
    }

    public Student(int id, string name, string major, string startdate, int graddate, string state, string country, string email, long phonenumber, string mailaddress)
    {
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._major = major;
        this._startdate = startdate;
        this._graddate = graddate;
        this._state = state;
        this._country = country;
        this._email = email;
        this._phonenumber = phonenumber;
        this._mailaddress = mailaddress;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student persix = new Student(02121966, "Blanka", "Electrical Engineering", "February 12, 1966", 2030, "Brasilia", "Brazil", "ShoutOfEarth@gmail.com", 4908001801976, "777 Amazon River Basin");
        Student perten = new Student(07021955, "Sagat", "Physical Education", "July 02, 1955", 2050, "Ayutthaya", "Thailand", "VanillaSagat@gmail.com", 39800928830, "311 King's Court");

        persix.Email = "qaz@bar.com";
        perten.Email = "foo@bar.com";

        Console.WriteLine("Instances of writing of a private field within a setter: {0}", Student.GetLog());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot! :D